# How to match begin URL with REGEX in Django

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm using this syntax for my API urls:

```
http://myhost/myapiname/X-Y-Z/web-service-name/
```

In Django urls.py, it looks like this:

```
url(r'api_s/2-0-0/get_client_profile/$', GetClientProfile.as_detail(), name='get_client_profile'),
```

Now, I'd like to redirect all 1-0-0 urls (deprecated webservices) to a specific view.
I tried something like `url(r'api_t/1-0-0*$', Deprecated.as_list(), name='deprecated')` but it can't be catch. I'm not used to REGEX so I'm missing something here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a dot before `*`:

```
url(r'api_t/1-0-0.*$', Deprecated.as_list(), name='deprecated')
```

The asterisk `*` sign means "repeat previous symbol zere or more times".  The dot `.` means "any char".  So `.*` will match any string.